# What is required for a monoidal category to have products/coproducts?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

What is required for a monoidal category to have products/coproducts?

If it helps the particular category I am interested in also has zero morphisms.

Comment: There are no reasonable conditions, because any category with products or coproducts is a monoidal category.

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I somehow thought that because products in a category can be extended to a tensor product, there were some way to do this the other way around.

Comment: Note that you could have a monoidal category that also has products (i.e., there are two monoidal structures on the category).

Answer (score 1):

A category with products is always monoidal, where the tensor product coincides with the product.

On the other way round (which is what I thought you're asking), a category that has all finite products, including the empty product, is called a **cartesian category**. So, the question is "*What does it take for a monoidal category to be cartesian?*". It turns out that a cartesian category is a monoidal category that is also

1. symmetric$^1$: $\gamma_{B,A}\circ\gamma_{A,B}=\mathbf{1}_{A\otimes B}$, where $\gamma_{A,B}:A\otimes B\overset{\sim}{\to}B\otimes A$ is the braiding isomorphism
2. and the monoidal structure of the category comes from the product, meaning $\otimes=\times$.

If the category is also closed (for any fixed object $A$, functor $(-)\otimes A$ has a right adjoint) then the category is cartesian closed.

I suggest you take a look at the book "Category theory for Computing Science", from Barr and Wells.

1: Note that for a monoidal category to be symmetric, it needs to be braided, too.